# How Linux struct buffer_head gets flushed?

Tags: caching, io, linux-kernel, filesystems, buffer

I'm wondering how a `buffer_head` struct in Linux gets flushed to the disk after it's marked as dirty. Now I'm assuming there are some background routines that periodically check if there are any buffers need to be flushed, but I cannot find which specific function or any subsystem does this job. Hope anyone can shed a light on this, thanks!

Comment: From the comment to the [struct buffer_header](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.3/source/include/linux/buffer_head.h#L60): "Nowadays the basic I/O unit is the bio, and buffer_heads are used for extracting block
mappings (via a get_block_t call), for tracking state within a page (via a page_mapping) and for wrapping bio submission for backward compatibility reasons (e.g. submit_bh).". That is, kernel doesn't track `buffer_head` structures. Instead, it is `bio` structure which is tracked.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks for your clarification. I noticed that in direct IO, the `submit_io` function will be called at some point. So I'm still curious about how those bio are tracked, and which routine does this job? For example, in Ext4 buffered IO, the write is done with the `mark_buffer_dirty` function: [link](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.10.57/source/fs/buffer.c#L2084). What's going on after that?